# Offline Routing in Postgres Sql

Tags: postgresql, routes, gis, postgis, offline

I am a newbie in Gis. I have written this code in Postgres SQL but unfortunately, it's so slow. it takes about 8 seconds which is not Optimal.I also created index on geom, source,target and primary key on id
what's the problem?

```
select * 

from pgr_dijkstra(
                'SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM tt_2po_4pgr',
                (
                    SELECT source FROM tt_2po_4pgr
                    ORDER BY geom_way <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(51.70103788375855,32.66101905786033),4326) LIMIT 1
                ),
                (
                    SELECT source FROM tt_2po_4pgr
                    ORDER BY geom_way <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(51.69098496437073,32.663204865281884),4326) limit 1
                ),false
                ) as di
                JOIN tt_2po_4pgr pt ON (di.edge = pt.id)
```

Comment: As with most SQL issues, start debugging to find slowest part: what are the times for each sub-query, what's the time for deijkstra without join, etc - to find the bottleneck and address it first.

Comment: *pgRouting* is highly optimized in its C code base, but large graphs will increase computation time; limiting your edges by the combined (and slightly expanded) bbox of your O/D points might help. however, you are running two *KNN* queries within the function; those queries are involved for large amount of vertices, and calling them from within the function might be an optimization fence; you could try to pre-compute the nearest vertices in a CTE. did you `VACUUM ANALYZE` your tables recently?